# Content of a text field not being cleared even though I am reassigning the value to an empty string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clear the text field upon submission of the form but for some reason it doesn't seem to clear. I have tried placing the statement to clear the text at different points but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I have tried using `textContent`, `nodeValue`, and `value` but for some reason it is not working. It was working before when I was originally doing everything using a function but then I decided to change the list item creation from only a function to a class and then use that class in the function.

Below is the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Drag and Drop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="form-container">
        <form id="content-form">
          <label for="text-content" id="text-content-label"
            >Enter your text:</label
          >
          <textarea
            name="text-content"
            id="text-content"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            maxlength="150"
          ></textarea>
          <input type="submit" id="submit-text-button" value="Submit!" />
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="list-container">
        <ul id="list-items-container"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/index.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And below is the JavaScript.

```
// Import drag and drop functions.
import {
  dragStart,
  dragEnd,
  dragEnter,
  dragLeave,
  dragOver,
  dragDrop
} from "./dragndropfunctions.js";

import { ID } from "./id.js";

// Local storage.
const listItemStorage = window.localStorage;
// Remove randid entry which always seems to show up for some reason.
listItemStorage.removeItem("randid");

// Grab text from text field and list items.
const textField = document.querySelector("#text-content");
const listItemsContainer = document.querySelector("#list-items-container");
const listItems = listItemsContainer.childNodes;

class NewListItem {
  constructor(textFieldText) {
    this.textFieldText = textFieldText;

    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    const listItemText = document.createTextNode(textFieldText);

    listItem.appendChild(listItemText);

    listItem.className = "list-item";
    listItem.setAttribute("draggable", true);

    listItemsContainer.appendChild(listItem);

    listItemStorage.setItem(ID(), listItem.textContent);
  }
}

function createAndAddNewListItem() {
  let textFieldText = textField.value;

  if (textFieldText.length > 0) {
    new NewListItem(textFieldText);
    textFieldText = "";
  } else {
    console.log("Please enter some text...");
  }
}

// Load pre-existing list items into the list during page onload.

function listItemOnload() {
  for (let key in listItemStorage) {
    if (listItemStorage.getItem(key) != null) {
      let listItem = document.createElement("li");
      const listItemText = document.createTextNode(
        listItemStorage.getItem(key)
      );
      listItem.appendChild(listItemText);

      addEventListenersToListItems();

      listItem.className = "list-item";
      listItem.setAttribute("draggable", true);

      listItemsContainer.appendChild(listItem);
    }
  }
}

function addEventListenersToListItems() {
  for (const item of listItems) {
    item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart, false);
    item.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd, false);
    item.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver, false);
    item.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter, false);
    item.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave, false);
    item.addEventListener("drop", dragDrop, false);
  }
}

// listItemStorage.clear();

console.log(typeof listItems);

export { createAndAddNewListItem,
```

Comment: maybe your js file is not updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is the line where you try to set the text content to an empty string?

```
if (textFieldText.length > 0) {
    new NewListItem(textFieldText);
    textFieldText = "";
```

If that's the case then the error is that, prior to this, you get the value from your text field via `let textFieldText = textField.value;`. When you assign a string to a variable it is not a pointer, it is a copy. Therefor when you set `textFieldText` to an empty string it won't affect the value on your textInput field. You have to set the value of the textInput field to an empty string:

`textField.value = "";`

If I am wrong with my assumption that this is how you try to change the value of the textField, than please post the code where you try to set the value of your textField.